# Celery service Active: inactive (dead) - Systemd, why isn't it starting?

Tags: systemd, background-process

I have set celery as a systemd as [mentioned here.](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/daemonizing.html#usage-systemd)

My celery.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Celery Service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=aj
Group=aj
EnvironmentFile=/etc/conf.d/celery
WorkingDirectory=/root/project
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN} -A ${CELERY_APP} multi start ${CELERY_NODES} \
  --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE} \
  --logfile=${CELERYD_LOG_FILE} --loglevel=${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL} ${CELERYD_OPTS}'
ExecStop=/bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN} multi stopwait ${CELERYD_NODES} \
  --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE}'
ExecReload=/bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN} -A ${CELERY_APP} multi restart ${CELERYD_NODES} \
  --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE} \
  --logfile=${CELERYD_LOG_FILE} --loglevel=${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL} ${CELERYD_OPTS}'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

My /etc/conf.d/celery

```
# Name of nodes to start
# here we have a single node
CELERYD_NODES="w1"
# or we could have three nodes:
#CELERYD_NODES="w1 w2 w3"

# Absolute or relative path to the 'celery' command:
#CELERY_BIN="/usr/local/bin/celery"
CELERY_BIN="/root/venv/bin/celery"

# App instance to use
# comment out this line if you don't use an app
CELERY_APP="project"
# or fully qualified:
#CELERY_APP="proj.tasks:app"

# How to call manage.py
CELERYD_MULTI="multi"

# Extra command-line arguments to the worker
CELERYD_OPTS="--time-limit=300 --concurrency=8"

# - %n will be replaced with the first part of the nodename.
# - %I will be replaced with the current child process index
#   and is important when using the prefork pool to avoid race conditions.
CELERYD_PID_FILE="/var/run/celery/%n.pid"
CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/var/log/celery/%n%I.log"
CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL="INFO"
```

Now when I am starting celery by typing `sudo service celery start` I am getting below response

```
● celery.service - Celery Service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/celery.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Oct 02 07:19:51 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-blr1-01 sh[30549]: > Starting nodes...
Oct 02 07:19:54 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-blr1-01 sh[30564]: celery multi v5.0.0 (singularity)
Oct 02 07:19:54 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-blr1-01 sh[30564]: > w1@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb01: DOWN
Oct 02 07:19:56 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-blr1-01 systemd[1]: Started Celery Service.
Oct 02 07:22:06 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-blr1-01 systemd[1]: Starting Celery Service...
Oct 02 07:22:09 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-blr1-01 sh[30701]: celery multi v5.0.0 (singularity)
Oct 02 07:22:09 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-blr1-01 sh[30701]: > Starting nodes...
Oct 02 07:22:14 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-blr1-01 sh[30715]: celery multi v5.0.0 (singularity)
Oct 02 07:22:14 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-blr1-01 sh[30715]: > w1@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb01: DOWN
Oct 02 07:22:16 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-blr1-01 systemd[1]: Started Celery Service.
```

Where am I going wrong?

p.s: I have faced many issues installing celery, seriously thinking of not using it as it way complicated and docs aren't helpful. Should I use other alternative?

Comment: When you run `service celery start` (or `systemctl start celery.service`), it invokes the `ExecStart` command. According to your configuration, that command would look like this: `/root/venv/bin/celery -A project multi start w1 w2 w3 ....`. As you can see from the status the output `w1@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb01: DOWN` comes from this command. This is the core of the problem, but I'm not familiar with celery to make any sense of that output. I guess it is unable to start a specific node? The logs under `/var/log/celery/` may have more information.

Comment: Thanks, @Haxiel does this mean that node is down? How can I check all nodes running on my machine? I'm using a virtual machine with the below config.
`Architecture:  x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):  32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order: Little Endian
CPU(s):1
On-line CPU(s) list: 0
Thread(s) per core:  1
Core(s) per socket:  1
Socket(s): 1
NUMA node(s): 1
Vendor ID: GenuineIntel
CPU family: 6
Model:63
Model name:Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2650L v3 @ 1.80GHz
Stepping:2
CPU MHz: 1799.998
BogoMIPS:  3599.99
Virtualization: VT-x
Hypervisor vendor: KVM
Virtualization type: full`

Comment: Sorry, I'm unable to answer that as I'm not familiar with this software. I was just hoping to point you in a helpful direction. As I have already mentioned, there should be one or more log files generated under /var/log/celery. Take a look at them and see if it helps.